# How do Streptococcus thermophilus and Lactobacillus bulgaricus precipitate the curd of swiss cheese?

Tags: microbiology, food

I learned in my food microbiology class that Streptococcus thermophilus and Lactobacillus bulgaricus precipitate the curd of swiss cheese. However, I was wondering what type of mechanisms do these bacteria use in order to accomplish this process.

Answer (score 1):

lactic acid bacteria ferment the disaccharide lactose present in high amounts in milk to the three-carbon compound lactic acid, which acidifies the milk. this causes the proteins also present in milk to denaturate and coagulate, forming curdles. other causes/methods of curdling can be application of heat, salts or by adding the enzyme chymosin (rennin).

Comment: my bad, I am quite new here. is this satisfactory?

Comment: Well, maybe *adding* a better link would strengthen it a little.

Comment: all concepts in my answer are pretty googlable. I understood from Chris' comment that just dropping Wikipedia links on everything is not the best way to answer, so yeah.